# disjoint Partition of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integer-partitions, set-partition

Hello I'm a bit confused by what this  definition means

$$DT_n = \{ \{C,D \} \mid C,D  ⊆ S_n \text{ and } C \cup D = S_n  \text{ and } C \cap D = \emptyset \} $$
where $S_n = \{1,2....n\}$ and n is a natural number. I'm given the examples of $DT_0 = \{\{\emptyset, \emptyset \}\}$and $DT_1=\{\{\{1 \}, \emptyset \}\}$. But I'm still a bit confused on how one would go about continuing the sets for say n = 2, or n = 3. Would $DT_2 = \{\{\{1\}, \emptyset\}, \{\{2\}, \emptyset\}\}$ and how would DT_3 work? Would that be sets of sets of two elements? I don't really understand the notation.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: $A$ and $B$ appear out of nowhere.  They are two disjoint sets that don't relate to anything, so you can remove that clause.  Having $\subseteq$ followed by $\wedge$ makes the string not a sentence.  Where did you see this?  It looks jumbled to me.

Comment: Hi sorry, I copied it wrong it should be C and D still

Comment: As well as Sn following the ⊆ symbol

Comment: $DT_3$ has $4$ members , which are $\{\phi, S_3\},\; \{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\},\; \{\{2\},\{1,3\}\},\; \{\{3\},\{1,2\}\}.$

Comment: I'm a bit confused why that would be the set, since how I interpret it is that for Dt2/Dt3 I would have a set of two sets only, since I interpret the initial {C,D} as meaning I would only have two members for all values of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$DT_n$ is a set.  Each element of the set is a set containing two sets.  Those two sets partition $S_n$.  $DT_n$ consists of all the partitions of $S_n$ into two disjoint sets.

Comment: Okay I see, so to make sure I understand would my $DT_2$ example be changed to {{1,2}, $\emptyset$} and {{1}, {2}} instead of what I wrote of {{{1},∅},{{2},∅}}? Thank you!

Comment: Yes,that is right.

Answer (score 1):

DT_3 has 4 two set partitions, one with empty set in it and three with a singleton in it.